# Detailed Balance condition for general state Markov Chains

Tags: measure-theory, markov-chains

I'm trying to understand the meaning of $dx$ and $dy$ in the following definition of the detailed balance condition given in Meyn and Tweedie's Markov Chains and Stochastic Stability:

> Given a measurable space $(\mathcal{X},\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X}))$, a transition kernel $P(\cdot,\cdot)$ over $\mathcal{X} \times \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$ and a measure $\pi$ on $\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$, the detailed balance condition holds if $\pi(dx)P(x,dy)=\pi(dy)P(y,dx). \tag{1}$

Since the function $P(x,\cdot)$ is a measure for each fixed $x \in \mathcal{X}$, given a measurable function $f$, I understand that the notation $\int f(y)P(x,dy)$ refers to the Lebesgue integral of $f$ w.r.t. the measure $P(x,\cdot)$. Equally, since $P(\cdot,A)$ is a measurable function for each $A \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$ fixed, I understand that $\int P(x,A)\pi(dx)$ refers to the Lebesgue integral of $P(\cdot,A)$ w.r.t. the measure $\pi(\cdot)$.

However, I don't understand what $dx$ and $dy$ mean in $(1)$ out of an integral sign, especially since the inequality involves two differentials in each side. Does it mean that, for each $A,B \in \mathcal{B}(\mathcal{X})$, it holds that
$\int_A \int_B\pi(dx)P(x,dy)=\int_A \int_B\pi(dy)P(y,dx)$?

Comment: This is more intuitive ( and less mathematical ) than Meyn and Tweedie but, assuming that you're trying to understand MCMC, you may find it helpful. It was for me many years ago. Everyone thinks differently so, if not, my apologies for the noise. https://cs.brown.edu/courses/csci2951-n/resources/understanding-metropolis-alg.pdf

Comment: @markleeds hi, I read the paper and while I found it useful to throw some intuition on how the MH acceptance probabilities were derived, it still uses the same differential notation out of an integral that I can't quite understand. For example, in identity $(2)$.

Comment: Hi Yagger. I'll check out identity (2) but I doubt that I can help.